# Что значит "x", возвращаемый typeid.name() в С++?

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Хотел бы уточнить, что означает "x". Typeid.name() возвращает "x", когда переменная типа long long. К сожалению, у меня выводится только первая буква типа переменной, т.е. если переменная типа int, то выведется "i", если char, то "c", из-за чего не до конца понятно, что выводится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандарт ***не*** оговаривает, какие конкретно имена выводятся для различных типов при использовании `typeid`.

У каждого компилятора своя система именования. Вот такая простенькая программка

```
int main() {
    cout << typeid(char).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(unsigned char *).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(main).name() << endl;
}
```

в VC++ выведет

```
char
unsigned char * __ptr64
int __cdecl(void)
```

а в [G++](https://ideone.com/UxgBUg) —

```
c
Ph
FivE
```

Так что лучшее, что можно вам посоветовать — обратиться к документации на ваш конкретный компилятор...

Comment: Скажите, а в каком разделе документации можно найти о системе наименования?

Comment: Думаю, что это тоже зависит от компилятора :)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)